# getting past CAS login with requests

Tags: authentication, http-post, python-requests, urllib2, cas

I'm trying to get past my university CAS login page to a database and then cycle through some already gathered urls, prettify them with BeautifulSoup and then download the PDF from a secondary URL (found with BeautifulSoup). I've been able to do all this with urllib while on my university network (thus not having to worry about getting past the login page) but I can't figure out how to get past the login page and then rework/redo my code that was in urllib.

I'm super new at everything and my understanding of all this is basic, but growing. I've searched all over and tried so many methods here and other places but a major problem I have is that I have no idea if any of this is really working.

EDIT: I really need help figuring out why I can't get past the login page. Everything I've tried, whenever I try to print out a page beyond the login page, it just returns the login page! Every time someone else has asked this type of question online there's invariably some answer of "oh, I figured it out using Python Requests" but there's never any other code besides what I've already tried below. I really would love some help figuring out what's wrong.

Here's what I have so far to get past the login page and my vain attempts to prettify just one url:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url for login page
url = "https://login.gmu.edu/login?service=http%3a%2f%2fmutex.gmu.edu%2flogin%3fqurl%3dezp.2aHR0cDovL3NlYXJjaC5wcm9xdWVzdC5jb20vcHFybD9hY2NvdW50aWQ9MTQ1NDE-"
# url for hidden page
shorturl = 'http://search.proquest.com.mutex.gmu.edu/hnpwashingtonpost/docview/141535544?accountid=14541'

payload = {
'username': 'myusername',
'password': 'mypassword'
#'_eventID': 'submit',
#'submit': 'LOGIN'
}

with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post(url, data=payload)
    result = c.get(shorturl)
    f = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    links = soup.find_all('embed')
    for link in links:
        print link
```

EDIT: Lukasa already showed me how to translate the code below into Requests. I really do need some help getting past the login since otherwise the rest of my script is pointless.

and this is the code that I have in urllib2 that I have no idea how to change to work with Requests (it imports an array of short urls from a temp file first):

```
# this is the section I need help translating to Requests although since I can't 
# prettify even one url after the login page it's a bit of a moot point at the moment
request2 = urllib2.Request(longurl)
print("... Sending HTTP GET to %s" % longurl)
f2 = opener.open(request2)
data = f2.read()
f2.close()
opener.close()

i = 0
while os.path.exists("Jun62-%s.pdf" % i ):
    i += 1

FILE = open("Jun62-%s.pdf" % i, "wb")
FILE.write(data)
FILE.close()
```

any and all help/advice would be so greatly appreciated. I'm seriously stymied as what to do and where to go from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a literal translation so you can see how `urllib2` translates into Requests. Arguably your code could do with some changes to be more idiomatic, but that wouldn't help here.

The important block is at the bottom:

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post(url, data=payload)
    result = c.get(shorturl)
    f = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    links = soup.find_all('embed')
    for link in links:
        link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1]
        longurl = link

        r = c.get(longurl)

        i = 0
        while os.path.exists("Jun62-%s.pdf" % i ):
            i += 1

        FILE = open("Jun62-%s.pdf" % i, "wb")
        FILE.write(r.content)
        FILE.close()
```

As you can see, this is one of the big reasons to move to Requests: your 6-line block becomes a single line with Requests.

Comment: thank you very much for helping with that translation. Any ideas though as to why I can't even get past the login page? every time I try to print f it keeps producing the login page. Everywhere I've searched that has remotely this same problem just says "thanks I figured it out with requests" but then no one posts any code so I can't see what they did that worked haha

Comment: Is the login working successfully? Might be worth confirming that the initial login request is doing what you want it to.